# Tests for combinational logic - product of sums simplification

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am trying to understand how to simplify the Boolean cover function
$(4+6)(12+14)(0+1+2+3)(11)(3)(9)(13)(10+14)(1+3+9)$

which is a stuck-at fault test cover function derived in [this paper](https://www.computer.org/csdl/trans/tc/1980/08/01675660.pdf). I know the result should be $(3)(9)(11)(13)(4)(14)$ or $(3)(9)(11)(13)(6)(14)$, but I don't know how to achieve it, or what Boolean laws to use to simplify the function. It is not described in detail in the paper.

Thanks